# In .NET, can you set the GC generation of an object, or otherwise indicate that it's about to go out of scope?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

.NET's garbage collector is a generational garbage collector, based on the philosophy that most allocated objects are short lived. As such, objects start in a "generation 0", where they can be easily collected (and often are), and longer lived objects are promoted to "generation 1" and "generation 2" where they are touched by more full sweeps. Generation 0 objects are often created when a method allocates an object as part of its state, then lets that object go out of scope when it exits.

However, sometimes those methods that allocate objects as state run for a very long time. Perhaps they block over an I/O call, or host a merge sort or database query with a bunch of threads. Garbage collections that happen during that time would promote these state objects to generations 1 and 2 during the execution of the method. While this is nice for keeping them out of the quick garbage collection sweeps, once this long-running method ends, I no longer have need for these state objects, and there are no callees that are holding any references to them anymore.

It would be nice, at this point, to be able to tell this to the garbage collector. to say that, yes, this object has existed for a long time, but it can be discarded soon, and the garbage collector can respond by moving the object to the gen 0 heap. Then, the next time a garbage collection needs to be performed (such as the next time this long-running method is called), the necessary memory can be reclaimed with a faster gen 0 sweep instead of a full, blocking sweep, thus reducing the unpredictability of the performance impacts of the garbage collector.

Some other information:

- Right now, my team alleviates this issue of unpredictable performance by storing these "local state" objects in giant mutable structs that are passed around via `ref` and `in` parameters. As I understand it, the .NET framework is poorly optimized for any structs beyond some small number of bytes (official sources say 16, though I've heard 24) as well as mutable structs, but I can't argue with the fact that these structs have automatic scope and will certainly get deallocated when the method returns - unless, of course, we can signal to the GC that a class is on its way out.
- I would be perfectly happy if this was a suggestion API, not a command, since ultimately the GC has to do what it has to do. Perhaps if it turns out that the object still had a reference somewhere, there would end up being some sort of performance penalty.
- I'm also open to answers about this facility existing in garbage collected frameworks other than .NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is - no, there is no such API. Most modern GCs are designed taking into account the "generational hypothesis" that most objects die young or live long. What you are describing is commonly referred to as "mid-life crisis" - objects living long enough to be promoted to the oldest generation, but quite immediately are no more needed. This is obviously by far not optimal for current GCs. A common way of avoiding it is to: reduce allocations (less chance of being promoted so we often stay in "die young" part) or reusing objects (so we land in "live long" part).

By heavily reusing structs and refs, you've taken the first approach. You may also think of reusing objects by pooling, like `ArrayPool<T>` or others.

Regarding the questions, you propose API for:

> "the garbage collector can respond by moving the object to the gen 0 heap"

Although it touches possible implementation details a lot, it is hardly imaginable to implement it efficiently. Many GCs, including .NET one, try at their best to not copy/move memory. Generations are just logical memory regions, with boundaries moved back and forth. Thus, "moving the object to the gen0" would require copying it (and possibly all its retained graph, to make is sensible) which would introduce an overhead much bigger than the potential benefit. Even worse, currently it could be done only during GC as we do not have concurrent compaction implemented (in general, moving objects while they are used).

> "As I understand it, the .NET framework is poorly optimized for any structs beyond some small number of bytes (official sources say 16, though I've heard 24) as well as mutable structs"

It seems like a little falsehood. .NET runtime makes a great optimizations around structs usage and if you are passing them around by `ref`, it is one of the most efficient approaches I can think of. Just be only aware of [defensive-copying pitfall](http://tooslowexception.com/readonly-ref-variables-in-parameters-and-readonly-structs/) that you may encounter when using `in` parameters.

Comment: `and if you are passing them around by ref` .... This is true. But sadly, hardly anyone does that. If you chose a struct rather than a class, it's often specifically because you wanted value semantics... and that works best with values small enough to fit reasonably in stack frame and not require more work to copy in their entirety than you'd have from copying a reference.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you do that if you are writing high-performance, memory-aware code, like the OP is trying to do. I agree that hardly anyone does that because often there is no need and thus, people do not know about such possibilities. And just two add two more cents - such small structs are even more often enregistered without touching the stack frame at all.

Comment: “*currently it could be done only during GC as we do not have concurrent compaction implemented*” even if you have it, there’s no way around first identifying the existing references that need to be adapted when moving the object, regardless of how you name the operation. The adaptation would be cheap in the OP’s case, i.e. when the number of existing references is expectedly zero, but on the other hand, there is no point in moving the object when the number of references has been proven to be zero. The solution is to just let the garbage collector do its work…

Comment: *"there’s no way around first identifying the existing references that need to be adapted"* that's what load barriers are used for, if I understand your concern correctly. *"The adaptation would be cheap in the OP’s case, i.e. when the number of existing references is expectedly zero"* - not sure what you mean by that..

Comment: I had no idea that moving an object to gen 0 meant actually copying it - yes, that would totally kill any performance benefit from cleaning it up. Thanks also for the suggestions about pooling.

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental principle of the .NET and Java garbage collectors is that unless memory has become fundamentally corrupted, it will never be possible to observe a non-null reference that does not identify a live object.  If the .NET Framework or Java Virtual Machine included a function to explicitly release the associated with a GC-managed reference, they would have to ensure that no observable references to the object exist anywhere before it could recycle the storage.  Because such assurance would cost about as much as a garbage-collection cycle, and because a GC cycle could free up storage for the object without having to be given a reference to it, being able to "manually" delete an object would seldom add much value.

Comment: I'm not really asking for a manual delete, though - most of that comes through IDisposable. I'm asking for more of a heuristic suggestion to improve the performance of deleting that object later.